# Bigquery if null and 0 then condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to add a condition if the row value is null or 0 then 0 else 1.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NUM_FRIEND IS NULL AND 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS friends_column
FROM TABLE
```

I get the following error:

```
No matching signature for operator and
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `case` expression, the syntax is:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NUM_FRIEND IS NULL OR NUM_FRIEND = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS friends_column
FROM TABLE;
```

You can simplify this to:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NUM_FRIEND <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS friends_column
FROM TABLE;
```

Or, instead of `0` and `1`, return a boolean:

```
SELECT (NUM_FRIEND <> 0) AS friends_column
FROM TABLE;
```